# Edit ListBox Container style

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Can i edit ListBox containter style via code not xaml?

Because:

I have my own ListBox items, and i'm doing this:

```
Expander.Expander a = new Expander.Expander();
                    a.IsExpanded = false;
                    TestItem TI = new TestItem();
                    TI.Tap += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri((App.Current as App).Course, UriKind.Relative));
                    };
                    TI.Tag = "/CourseInfoPage.xaml";
                    ListBox list = new ListBox();
                    list.Items.Add(TI);
                    list.Height = 200;
                    a.Content = list;
                    a.HeaderContent = Semestris.Name;

                    Stack.Children.Add(a);
```

I need items to stretch on the full width of the ListBox. Before in my program i used this xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
```

But now i have only C# and native ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can set the `Style` behind code:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Style ListBoxItemStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
    ListBoxItemStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
    Resources.Add(typeof(ListBoxItem), ListBoxItemStyle);
}
```